# How to code a view as NSMenuItem in cocoa?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I can work with NSMenu or NSMenuItem but I see apple use color tag in Finder which has animation also, I wander how we could code some thing like this? because all NSMenuItem offer is a string and just one clickable object in a row as a NSMenuItem, but if you look to this image it gave multi clickable object in single row and it has color and animation, almost defining a NSView not just a NSMenuItem, So how we can code something like that as a NSMenuItem?

[image: A screenshot of Mac manu bar with Finder as the selected application, showing the custom tag icons that appear on in the 'File' menu.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSMenuItem` has a [`view`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsmenuitem/1514835-view) property that you can set.

See [views in menu items](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/ViewsInMenuItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005166-SW1).